# Equal height sections in custom Headway Theme

Tags: css, javascript, html5

I have this piece of code:

```
<section class="row row-3">
      <section class="column column-1 grid-width-19 grid-left-0">
      <section class="column column-2 grid-width-5 grid-left-0">
</section>
```

The first section of the row (column-1) will have variable height depending on the content.
The second section (column-2) is the sidebar, and always has the same content (widgets) and height.
I now need this sidebar (column-2)section to be the same height as the first (column-1)section.

As I'm using headway Themes, so I cannot add any div's, or ID's to the layout. I therefor don't know how to use the scripts I find on the internet.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this without touching theme files either by using a child theme or  [Writing a Custom Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin),

To include only css I'd use plugin rather than a child theme.

### Example -

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Styles
Description: My Custom Styles for THEME-NAME 
*/
//Create a `my-style.css` in plugin folder    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse64258_custom_styles' );
function wpse64258_custom_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'my-style', plugins_url('my-style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style' );
}
?>
```

> **For CSS Code read these articles -**
>
> - [4 Methods For Creating Equal Height Columns In CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/)
> - [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)